# Getting all elements concatenate in a string with LINQ

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have the following classes:

```
public class People 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<Right> Rights { get; set; }
}

public class Right
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Val { get; set; }
}
```

With the following values:

- People: ID: 1

  - Right:

    - ID: 1
    - Val: 5
  - Right:

    - ID: 2
    - Val: 4

I would like to retrieve all `Val` rights (in a single string) for the people.

So for people with ID 1 : getting `"5,4"`.

Comment: Your code is broken: `public List<Right> { get; set; }`

Comment: Sounds like a mixture of Where, Select and String.Join should work for you.

Comment: I updated to correct it.

Comment: @Jon you are certainly right but I didn't succeed.

Comment: Do you have more than one People object object with the same id, for which you want to get all Right objects from all People objects with the same id?

Comment: @Bronzato: That suggests you've tried something - which you should include in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<People> list = ...;

string result = string.Join(",", (people.First(p => p.ID == 1)).Rights.Select(r => r.Val));
```

Example :

```
        List<People> people = new List<People>()
        {
            new People() 
            {
                ID = 1, Rights = new List<Right>()
                {
                    new Right() { ID = 1, Val = 5 }, 
                    new Right() { ID = 2, Val = 10 }, 
                }
            },

            new People() 
            {
                ID = 2, Rights = new List<Right>()
                {
                    new Right() { ID = 1, Val = 6 }, 
                    new Right() { ID = 2, Val = 11 }, 
                }
            }
        };

        string result = string.Join(",", (people.First(p => p.ID == 1)).Rights.Select(r => r.Val));

        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output: `5, 10`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SelectMany` to flatten a structure, so something like:

```
var vals = people.Where(p => p.ID == 1)
                 .SelectMany(p => p.Rights.Select(r => Val));

var str = String.Join(",", vals.Select(v => v.ToString());
```